# get data from razor page that pass by BindProperty

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

***Update:*** I Have two Razor Page, In the first page I got person information and in second page I going to get project information from that person that submitted information in first page, in second page(ProjectInformation table) I save data that have relation with first page(projectOwner table) information in ***personId***,

***End of Update***

I pass "user email" in razorPage that is BindProperty like this

```
  [BindProperty]
  public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }
  public IActionResult OnGet(string OwnerId)
    {
        OwnerEmail = OwnerId;
        return Page();
    }
```

In RazorPage show like this

```
@page
@model Sunn.Raz.Pages.Order.ProjectOrderModel
@using Sunn.Model
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "ProjectOrder";
}

<h4>ProjectOrder</h4>
    @Model.OwnerEmail
```

And I have **UserEmail** in RasorPage, Now when user click on ***submit*** Button I want seen email again to **OnPost()** method,

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {

        var ownerId = _context.ProjectOwners.Where(x => x.Email == OwnerEmail).Select(m => new { m.Id });
    }
```

but **userEmail** is **Null**, 
How can I have value of ***user email(OwnerEmail)*** in **OnPostAsync()**?
***Update2:***
In Razor Page to access our property use like this

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProjectOrder.ProjectOwnerId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ProjectOrder.ProjectOwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProjectOwnerId"></select>
                </div>
```

It's mean before **"ProjectOwnerId"** use **"ProjectOrder"**

I set the first answer in my code but in onPostAsync(), **"ProjectOwnerId"** is zero

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="OwnerEmail" />
```

Comment: Where in the shown example do you have **`UserEmail`**. The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: I updated and describe about scenario

Answer (score 0):

On Razor Pages,you just display the value of `OwnerEmail` but do not post its data when you submit the form.Try to add a hidden type input to make it:

```
<form method="post">
    <h4>ProjectOrder</h4>
    @Model.OwnerEmail

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="OwnerEmail"/>

    <button type="submit">
       Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: for razor VIEW it"s work but in razor page that use modelbinding not working

Comment: @sunny It works when I try in razor pages.But I only have one page while you have two pages,is that the difference?Could you explain more on your code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I update the code and describe that binding property still not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Help
I do like this but I'm not sure that is best way, but is work

1. I define BindProperty in Project

   [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]

   ```
   public int OwnerId { get; set; }
   ```
2. Fill it in OnGet()

   this.OwnerId = OwnerId;
3. in RazorPage do this

   @{ Model.ProjectOrder.ProjectOwnerId = Model.OwnerId; }